# Spring JPA audting is not invoked

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented spring data jpa auditing. Below is my configuration file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapplication.test")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myapplication.test.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider", dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider")
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private static final Logger loggger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationProperties configProps;

    @Bean("auditorProvider")
    public AuditorAware<Integer> auditorProvider() {
        return () -> {
            AuthenticationToken authentication = (AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            return (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) ? authentication.getUser().getUserId() : null;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider() {
        return () -> GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }

}
```

Here is my entity super class

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false)
    private Integer createdBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_on", updatable = false)
    private Date createdOn;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "last_updated_by")
    private Integer updatedBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_updated_on")
    private Date updatedOn;

}
```

auditorProvider is getting the user id from the Spring Security context. I have used spring-security-oauth2.

below the versions of the libraries I am having

```
<spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>5.2.9.Final</hibernate.version>
<springsecurity.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
<springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.12.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
```

When I save an entity the auditing methods are not getting called(in debug) and created/updated fields are not updated in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the hibernate annotations, you should use the spring data ones like:

```
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@CreatedDate
private long createdDate;

@Column(name = "modified_date")
@LastModifiedDate
private long modifiedDate;
```

This always worked for me, as specified in this tutorial:  [Jpa Auditing](http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)